# how can i render an array of tasks when a project instance is clicked on?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a todo list and i can not properly push a task into a project instance.

I tried creating a selectProject function that would target the project instance by a click which the user would then be able to add a and see it via the renderTasks function. Below is that javascript code that i'm having the issue with.

```js
//class for single project
class Project {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.tasksArr = [];
    }
    get nameOfProject() {
        return this.name;
    }
    get tasksArray() {
        return this.tasksArr;
    }
    isEmpty() {
        return this.tasksArr.length == 0;
    }
    addTasksToProject(name, dueDate) {
        let newTask = new Task(name, dueDate);
        this.tasksArr.push(newTask);
        return newTask
    }
}
//class for a group of projects 
class Projects {
    constructor() {
        this.listOfProjects = [new Project("Sample Project")];
    }
    addProjectToList(name) {
        let p = new Project(name);
        this.listOfProjects.push(p);
        return p
    }
    get allProjects() {
       return this.listOfProjects;
    }
    get numOfProjects() {
        return this.listOfProjects.length;
    }
}

class Task {
    constructor(name, dueDate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dueDate = dueDate;
        this.completed = false;
    }
}

//global vars

let projects = new Projects();
let project = new Project();
let projArr = projects.allProjects;
let taskArr = project.tasksArray;
let projectId = 0;
let selectedProj = null;

function renderTasks(currentProj) {
    const taskList = document.getElementById("task-list");
    if (currentProj.isEmpty) {
        taskList.textContent = "this project currently has no task. Please add a task below";
    } else if (!currentProj.isEmpty) {
        taskList.textContent = "";
        taskArr.forEach(task => {
            const newTaskDiv = document.createElement("div");
            newTaskDiv.textContent = task.name;
            newTaskDiv.classList.add("task-item");
            taskList.appendChild(newTaskDiv);
        });
    }
}

function selectProject(e) {
    let currentProj = projArr[e.currentTarget.id];
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
    selectedProj = currentProj;
    renderTasks(selectedProj);
    console.log(taskArr);
    console.log(currentProj.name);
}

projArr.forEach(renderProjects);
function renderProjects(project) {
  const newProjectDiv = document.createElement("div");
  const dltBtn = document.createElement("button");
  const projectDom = document.getElementById("project-list");
    newProjectDiv.textContent = project.nameOfProject;
    dltBtn.textContent = "delete";
    newProjectDiv.classList.add("project-item");
    newProjectDiv.appendChild(dltBtn);
    projectDom.append(newProjectDiv);
    newProjectDiv.id = projectId;
    dltBtn.addEventListener("click", (index) => {
        if(projArr[index] === dltBtn[index]) {
            projArr.splice(projArr.indexOf(project), 1);
            newProjectDiv.remove();
            resetIds(Number(newProjectDiv.id));
            projectDom.listCounter.textContent = projects.numOfProjects;
            projectId -= 1;
        }
    });
    newProjectDiv.addEventListener("click", selectProject);
    projectId++;
    console.log(project.nameOfProject);
}

function resetIds(index) {
    for (let i = index; i < projArr.length; i++) {
        const element = document.getElementById(i+1);
        console.log(i+1)
        element.id = i;
    }
}

//eventListeners

const addBtn = document.getElementById("add");
const addTask = document.getElementById("addTask")
addBtn.addEventListener("click", addProjectBtn);
addTask.addEventListener("click", addTaskBtn)

function addProjectBtn() {
    let projName = prompt("name");
    let pushProj = projects.addProjectToList(projName);
    renderProjects(pushProj);
    console.log(projects.allProjects);
}

function addTaskBtn() {
    let taskName = prompt("task name");
    let pushTask = project.addTasksToProject(taskName);
    renderTasks(pushTask);
    console.log(project);
    console.log(renderTasks(pushTask))
}
```

```html
<button id="add">add project</button>
<button id="addTask">addTask</button>

<div class="container"></div>
<div id="project-list" class="project-list"></div>
<div id="task-list"></div>
```

Comment: Looks to me like it worked.  Are you complaining about the fact that it logs `undefined` when you do `console.log(renderTasks(pushTask))`?  Because your `renderTasks` function doesn't return a value (so the return value is `undefined` by default and that is what you passed to `console.log`).

Comment: @Wyck when i click on the project even after adding a task to that project i tells me that there are no tasks assigned to the project.

Comment: Well `isEmpty` is a function, so  you'll have to call it with `isEmpty()` instead of just `if (currentProj.isEmpty) {`  A function as a value is truthy so `currentProj.isEmpty` is truthy and the affirmative case of your `if` is always taken.  This is just a typo.